# R Programming: What Happens to a dangling child environment when its parent has been removed?

Tags: r

I have googled on this subject to no avail and hope that someone will answer this question for me.

BTW, parent.env(child) shows the parent environment x but since I have removed it, it doesn't make sense to me why parent.env(child) would still return that environment:

e.g.

```
x<-new.env()
child<-new.env(parent=x)
print(x) # shows <environment: 0x00000000217b8498>
parent.env(child) # shows <environment: 0x00000000217b8498>
rm(x)
parent.env(child) # still shows <environment: 0x00000000217b8498>
```

Appreciate any help on this question.

Answer (score 4):

The parent environment doesn't get removed as `child` depends on it. `rm` will remove a name from the memory nametable and then modify the state of values that were bound to the name. `gc` will handle the final removal and freeing of memory, but only if there are no further references to the value.

Consider the following:

```
x$largevec <- numeric(1e7)
memory.size()
[1] 99.69
rm(x)
gc()
           used (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb) max used (Mb)
Ncells   217423 11.7     460000  24.6   350000 18.7
Vcells 10399066 79.4   15376413 117.4 10402077 79.4
memory.size()
[1] 97.51
rm(child)
gc()
         used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
Ncells 217416 11.7     460000 24.6   350000 18.7
Vcells 399008  3.1   12301130 93.9 10402077 79.4
memory.size()
[1] 21.2
```

The memory allocated for `largevec` in `x` doesn't get freed until `child` is removed as there are still references to it's environment.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful!

Comment: FWIW I think the "completely" is misleading here, implying it's "somewhat removed." To say that `largevec` "isn't needed" isn't quite accurate either, as you can still access the values _via_ the `child` environment, so it definitely is still needed even if the `x` binding is removed.

Comment: after deleting `x`, you can access `largevec` using `with(child, largevec)` - just like any other components of `x` (provided that nothing with the same name exists in `child`). that is exactly the point of not removing an environment as long as it is a parent for another environment.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've clarified it.

Answer (score 4):

In your example, the parent environment **hasn't been removed**.

Calling `rm(x)` doesn't remove the object itself, it only removes the binding
of the name `x` from the environment where `rm()` was called in. As long as
an object is reachable from the current environment, it won't ever be
removed.

Paraphrasing the beginning of the [Names and Values
chapter](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/names-values.html) of the Advanced R book,
it may be helpful to think of `x <- new.env()` as doing two things: creating
an environment object, and then binding the object to the name `x` in the
current environment.

Even if this original binding is removed, as long as we can reach the object,
we can restore a binding to it in the global environment. Here's an extension
of your example to demonstrate:

```r
x <- new.env()
x
#> <environment: 0x0000000015043a78>
x$foo <- "bar"

y <- new.env(parent = x)
parent.env(y)
#> <environment: 0x0000000015043a78>

rm(x)
parent.env(y)
#> <environment: 0x0000000015043a78>

z <- parent.env(y)

z # the name z is now bound to the same object that x was
#> <environment: 0x0000000015043a78>
z$foo
#> [1] "bar"
```

So to answer the titular question: **it's not possible to reach a state where
the parent environment of a still-existing child environment has been
removed.**

Created on 2018-08-23 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).